# Stored procedure SQL raiserror not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a Stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. I have programming experience but I can't figure this out... Maybe I've just been looking at it too long! The first example raises the error but the second doesn't...Any ideas...

```
ALTER PROC master_class
--EXTERNAL VARIABLES
   @iSFname varchar(20),
   @iSLname varchar(20),
   @iDOB date
AS
--INTERNAL VARIABLES
DECLARE @AGE int
DECLARE @ReturnValue int
DECLARE @class nvarchar

--get student age
SELECT @AGE = 32        
SELECT @class = 'science'

    --ERROR CHECKS      
    --check ward age rule
    IF (@AGE > 18)
        BEGIN           
            RAISERROR('This Person cannot be submitted to this class!', 16, 1)
            RETURN 99
        END
```

Then execute

```
  EXECUTE [School].[dbo].[master_class] 'john', 'o connor', '08-01-1981'
```

The above will return 'This Person cannot be submitted to this class!'. If i change the if condition to

```
IF (@AGE > 18 AND @class = 'science')
        BEGIN           
            RAISERROR('This Person cannot be submitted to this class!', 16, 1)
            RETURN 99
        END
```

It will execute when it shouldn't!!!!...WHY is this, when @class = 'science' is true and Age is over 18 is true

Any feedback would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nvarchar` without a length defaults to `nvarchar(1)` (oddly, `varchar` defaults to 30, and both default to 30 in a `cast`)

```
Declare class nvarchar = 'science'

Select @class

's'
```

Comment: Cheers Laurence...Works!:)